# Загрузка файлов в Django

Tags: python, django

setting.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static') 

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

форма

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

views.py

```
def uploads(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = upload(request.POST, request.FILES)


        return HttpResponse(request.FILES['file'].temporary_file_path)


    else:
        form = upload()
    return render_to_response('ff.html', {'form': form})
```

`request.FILES['file'].temporary_file_path` должен возвращать путь к временному файлу.В папке **media** файл отсутствует, а в браузере отображается только знак `>`

в модели формы только поле `FileField()`. При добавлении в него `upload_to` в консоли выдается ошибка `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upload_to'`

Comment: Всё же `charset` — это не путь к файлу. Вы можете выводить, например, `name` — имя загруженного файла. Впрочем, суть не в этом. Файл сохраняется в место, указанное в `upload_to` после вызова `form.save()`, которого у вас нет. Приведите, кстати, ещё код для upload.

Comment: `upload_to` есть у файлового поля в модели (т.е. в описании таблицы базы данных). Если вы создаёте форму на основе модели, то всё легко. Если вы просто сделали форму, то файл нужно обрабатывать вручную. Например, вставить команду для копирования в нужное место.

Comment: Добавил в ответ пару абзацев про копирование файла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кратко: *файл, загружаемый через форму, необходимо обработать, чего ваша программа не делает*.

Когда вы загружаете файл, Django сперва помещает его во временно хранилище. Маленькие файл размещаются в памяти, большие — в системной временной директории (на Linux это `/tmp/`).

Пример (UploadFileForm — форма, содержащая поле file типа FileField):

```
def upload_file(request):
    # Если метод POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Заполняем форму полученными данными
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # Если данные валидны
        if form.is_valid():
            # обрабатываем файл
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            # перенаправляем на другую страницу
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    # Если другой метод (обычно GET)
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    # Выводим форму загрузки
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Перенаправление делают для того, чтобы при обновлении страницы файл не загружался повторно. `handle_uploaded_file` — функция обработки файла, её нужно писать самому.

Пример копирования содержимого полученного файла в файл `/srv/media/data.txt`:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('/srv/media/data.txt', 'wb+') as dest:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            dest.write(chunk)
```

Нужно использовать `chunks`, так как копирование по частям меньше нагружает систему. Просто копирование из временной папки тоже не подходит, так как файл может быть загружен в память.

Путь, по которому будет сохраняться файл можно сформировать самому из `MEDIA_ROOT` и имени загруженного файла с помощью `os.path.join`.

Обрабатывать файл можно по-разному. Можно прочитать его содержимое целиком при помощи метода `read()` или по частям с помощью метода `chunks()` и что-то с ним сделать. Но чаще всего файл просто сохраняют в какую-либо директорию, где он будет в дальнейшем хранится.

Также Django предоставляет удобный способ. Если файл также хранится в модели, то его можно сохранить в указанное место одним вызовом. Для этого в модели вы создаёте поле типа `FileField` с аргументом `upload_to`, содержащим путь, по которому будет размёщён файл. Если вы создавали форму на основе модели (то есть, с помощью `ModelForm`), то достаточно команды

```
form.save()
```

для сохранения файла в указанное место. Также вы сможете загружать файлы через админку.

[Загрузка файлов в Django](http://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/http/file-uploads.html)